# Why does kubeadm upgrade get stuck waiting for the kubelet to restart the component?

Tags: kubernetes

I'm trying to upgrade a Kubernetes multi-master cluster from v1.8.5 to v1.9.1 on Ubuntu 1604 LTS.

When I run `sudo kubeadm upgrade apply v1.9.1` it gets as far as backing up the old manifest for `kube-apiserver.yaml` and then displays this:

> [upgrade/staticpods] Waiting for the kubelet to restart the component

It then waits for 60 seconds (apparently a [hard-coded time-out](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubeadm/issues/413) in kubeadm) before restoring the original state.

There's nothing obvious in the logs. What could be the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out to be a problem with the single `nodeName` in the `kubeadm-config` being hard-coded to the name of one of the other masters.

I edited it with this command:

```
kubectl edit cm -n kube-system kubeadm-config -o yaml
```

and changed the `nodeName` in the `MasterConfiguration` section to match the name of the master being upgraded, and then it worked.